# What's the significance of the bite marks on the victim's hands in "Reptile"?

Tags: reptile

In *Reptile* (2023 film), Detective Tom Nichols (Benicio del Toro), who is investigating the murder of a real estate agent named Summer (Matilda Lutz), discovers that Summer has human bite marks on her hands.

This causes Tom to investigate further. He takes a dental impression of the main suspect, Sam Gifford, the victim’s ex-husband, and sends it to a forensic odontologist for analysis, but the results are inconclusive as the bite marks are not deep enough.

Later in the film, we find out that the murder was orchestrated by

> Will Grady (Justin Timberlake), who is collaborating with some corrupt cops.

This makes me wonder why the killer or someone else bit Summer’s hands in the first place.

##### What's the significance of the bite marks? Who bit Summer’s hands, and why were her hands bitten?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a source of definitive answers coming out for this movie to soon, though:

> (Vic's Wife): What is this, "Active Duty Security Consulting"?
>
> Tom: What's up with the bulldog?
>
> Wally: *Because when we bite, we never let go.*

> Probably a bit too literal, but Wally is the only one with the sheer strength to  have stabbed her that many times and stab so hard that it gets stuck.

> He would also know to put on a limp to point the finger at someone else.

> And when Allen says he's keeping the car for someone, that someone could be Wally.

As to why? She probably struggled and it was a way that he could restrain her.
Use his teeth instead of cuffs.

I've only seen it once so maybe I missed something.

Read more: https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=reptile